How ActiveMQ Artemis fail-over works with replication as HA policy
I have designed an ActiveMQ Artemis 2.19.1 symmetric cluster connection with 3 live-backup pairs to get rid of split-brain issue. Due to some constraints I had to adopt replication instead of shared storage. I have also grouped 1 live-backup pair as group1, group2 and group3 using <group-name>.
Recently I faced a production issue, where live from group-2 went down with Java Heap Memory issue. In log, it showed errors sequentially as follows:
ERROR AMQ224088 : Timeout (10 seconds) on acceptor during protocol handshake with /xxx.x.xxx.xx:xxxx has occured.

WARN AMQ22196 : Could not find binding with id=3,979,507,184 on routeFromCluster for message=CoreMessage[........

ERROR AMQ224013 : failed to expire messages for queue: xxxx

WARN AMQ212037 : Connection Failure to /xxx.xx.xxx.xx has been detected: Java heap Space [code=GENERIC_EXCEPTION]

ERROR AMQ224016 : Caught exception: ActiveMQIllegalStateException[errortype=ILLEGAL_STATE message=AMQ229027: Could not find referrence on consumer ID=0, mesaageId = 3,979,701,033 queue= xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx]

ERROR AMQ229028: Consumer 0 doesn't exist on the server

(.....continues in same sequence for around 1min)
FINALLY,
16:02 ERROR There is a possible split brain on nodeID xxxxxxxxx. Topology update ignored.

Then backup from group-2 became live but it couldn't process whose logs are as follows:
16:02 INFO Initiating qurom vote
16:02 INFO Received all quorum votes
16:02 INFO Failing over based on quorum vote results
16:02 INFO Server is now live
.
.
.
16:03 INFO Auto removing Queue xxxxxxx 
16:17 WARN Connection failure to xxx.x.xxx.xx
16:19 Auto removing address

Meanwhile the cluster had been restarted at around 16:43
17:02 INFO AMQ221000: backup Message broker is starting with configuration Broker Configuration.

My queries are:
How replication happens actually and if master is already out of the network, how data can be replicated to backup?There is no log regarding data replication.Does that mean, it did not happen at all from 16:02 till 16:43?
LOGS:
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/f5IEwy96.jpg "log1"
[2]: https://i.sstatic.net/rUD5b3gk.jpg "log2"
[3]: https://i.sstatic.net/pBk8IVSf.jpg "log3"
[4]: https://i.sstatic.net/t1V6tpyf.jpg "log4"

You've got too many questions here. Every post on Stack Overflow should ask a single question. Also, this isn't about programming. Due to these issues your question is likely to be closed.

Updated my post. Please suggest. Note:- Due to security concerns, I can't post the exact logs here.

When the primary broker in group-2 failed and the backup activated you said, "it couldn't process," and you shared some log entries. However, those log entries look pretty normal to me. What exactly do you mean that "it couldn't process"? Also, what about those log entries is problematic?

What do you mean, "How replication happens actually and if master is already out of the network"? Replication happens between a primary and a backup. If you don't have a primary broker then no replication can take place. Did you expect replication to happen after the primary broker failed? If so, why?

I strongly recommend you upgrade to the latest release of ActiveMQ Artemis. Version 2.19.1 is two and a half years old now and there's been 20 releases since then. Also, I recommend you look at the ZooKeeper integration which will allow you to use a single primary/backup pair of brokers and still avoid split-brain.

'It couldn't process' - I mean, it couldn't process the messages those were stuck in queue of primary when primary got shut down due to java heap issue.                Does replication happens continuously between primary and backup because as mentioned in doc I understood all primary data gets synchronized with backup when primary is dead and backup becomes live.

Updated post with primary-backup broker file configuration. Please let me know if anything wrong with it.

ERROR AMQ224013 : failed to expire messages for queue: xxxx  - Does this indicate that queue is full ? Can it be caused by producer producing the messages and consumer is unable to consume with almost equal pace ? How can I stop this kind of issue in future?

I still don't understand what "it couldn't process" actually means. What is it? Is the backup broker not able to load the messages that were replicated from the primary? Or is the backup loading the messages fine but the client(s) somehow can't process them? Please clarify.

When a primary and backup first connect with each other there is an initial synchronization phase so that the backup receives all the existing data from the primary. After that synchronization is complete then the primary will replicate data to the backup in real time. Once the primary dies there is no way to get any data from it anymore so the backup must operate based on the data it already received.

The AMQ224013 error message does not indicate that the queue is full. It simply indicates that there was a problem expiring messages. There should be a stack-trace associated with that log entry to clarify exactly what went wrong. That said, that message was removed from the code-base in version 2.22.0 via ARTEMIS-3778 (which is another reason to upgrade). Messages can expire because consumers aren't keeping up. Fixing that problem depends on why exactly it's happening in the first place (which you don't indicate).

After a quick look at your configuration I don't see anything wrong.

Where does the ActiveMQ Artemis documentation say that "all primary data gets synchronized with backup when primary is dead and backup becomes live"?

Regarding "it couldn't process" - yes, client(s) somehow can't process them. For what happened on artemis primary server side I have updated post with logs, when this issue started to happen. I have masked some data for security reasons. I have highlighted "Java heap space" issue in log-2. Does that indicate something specific? Please let me know if more logs needed to understand the issue.

The broker can run out of memory for all kinds of reasons although typically it's because consumers aren't keeping up with producers so messages are building up and you probably have paging misconfigured. In any case, the logs you shared don't really shed any light on the underlying cause of the problem. Have you upgraded yet? If not, why not?

Also my address settings has - true
and true. So, do I also need to have false and false as I can see a lot of "AMQ222196-could-not-find-binding-with...." warnings ?

2.19.1 is the version that is compatible with Java 8. My PROD is on Java 8, there are other tools on my PROD box those also need Java 8. Let me reconfigure paging and come back with the results. Appreciate your prompt response.

Since my artemis is using all default configuration for paging, Does it actually always busy in paging ? What happens when consumer slows down ?
